# Array in value in input type checkbox?

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
<form action="next.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>Attuck</td>
      <td>paulattuck@yahoo.com</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="paulattuck@yahoo.com" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Bond</td>
      <td>jamesbond@yahoo.com</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="jamesbond@yahoo.com" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Last</td>
      <td>lastname@yahoo.com</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="lastname@yahoo.com" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and if i checked all checkbox and send form to **next.php** i can:

```
print_r($_POST['tags']);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => paulattuck@yahoo.com
    [1] => jamesbond@yahoo.com
    [2] => lastname@yahoo.com
)
```

How can i make:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => array ([0] => Paul
                      [1] => Attuck
                      [2] => paulattuck@yahoo.com)
        [1] => array ([0] => James
                      [1] => Bond
                      [2] => jamesbond@yahoo.com)
        [2] => array ([0] => Last
                      [1] => Name
                      [2] => lastname@yahoo.com)
    )
```

? I try use serialize but this make " - dont can use this in html form.

Comment: There is really no way to achieve what you want. You'll have to use some workaround such as those posted by Rickesh and Eugen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make sure there is one character forbidden in the name fields (I use `|` here), you can do

```
<tr>
      <td>Paul</td>
      <td>Attuck</td>
      <td>paulattuck@yahoo.com</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value="Paul|Attuck|paulattuck@yahoo.com" /></td>
</tr>
```

And will get

```
print_r($_POST['tags']);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => Paul|Attuck|paulattuck@yahoo.com
    [1] => James|Bond|jamesbond@yahoo.com
    [2] => Last|Name|lastname@yahoo.com
)
```

Which you can transform by

```
$names=array();
foreach ($_POST['tags']) as $tag)
  $names[]=explode('|',$tag,3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to give values like :

```
value="Paul,Attuck,paulattuck@yahoo.com"
```

And than explode it with `,` you will get your desire array.

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach is to submit a value that can be used in subsequent database queries that will return the rest of the data. I suggest you consider that approach first.

If you really want to submit all fields, the simplest way is to separate them with a character that is not used in the fields and then split at the server, as others have commented.